# visual studio 2013 windows application using ms access database

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2010, network-shares

1. I created a visual studio 2013 windows application(Information System), and i'm planning
   to install in 5 computer machine and login their own user account.
2. My problem is... what is/are step/s to do for the 5 computer machine to access the single 
   access database?
3. Is there any technique aside from sharing the access database via LAN?

Is there someone here who could guide me? please...

emman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the short question, just shared access to the database file itself.

Refer to the following MS articles that explains the concepts succinctly.  The process is the same even if the front end is C#.

```
Office 2007: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/ways-to-share-an-access-database-HA010279159.aspx
Office 2010: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/ways-to-share-an-access-database-HA010342110.aspx
Office 2013: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/ways-to-share-an-access-desktop-database-HA102749577.aspx
```

You are specifically interested in the database portion of 'splitting a database'